# Google Analytics display confusing data in segments

Tags: google-analytics

I created a Fleet Page Segment on GA to get only tracking activities for **/fleet** and **/fleet/**

[image]

On Pageviews I see **81** views but there are only **23** views on **/fleet/** and **9** views on **/fleet**

[image]

My question is why GA calculated other url views when I set on the Fleet Page segment to filter only **/fleet** and **/fleet/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segment is isolating the sessions that have seen both the `/fleet` and `/fleet/` pages (if you wanted to isolate the sessions that have seen either one or the other you should use OR instead of AND).

That said, the behavior you see in the report is because it shows viewing all the pages viewed by the sessions that visited the pages defined in your segment. So you are not filtering to see only those two pages, but you are seeing all the pages viewed by sessions who respect the condition of your segment.

Comment: I see. So how can I create a segment that filter only ```/fleet``` and ```/fleet/``` page views?

Comment: You don't need a segment, just use filter in the report (input field with magnifying glass) if you want to see details for only these two pages.